# Calling await inside an onTap closure in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await

I have a button that writes to the `SharedPreferences` object. Creating the instance of `SharedPreferences` is asynchronous, just as writing to it.

My first implementation of the onTap closure is:

```
Future<void> saveUserName() async {
    print("Saving user: $this");
    final prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    await prefs.setString('name', 'Joe User');
  }
```

What bothers me is the two `await` calls inside this event handler. Will this block the GUI?

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: No, this won't block the GUI. This is the best way. Check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SmTCmDMi4BY

Comment: `async/await` doesn't block anything, but delays further execution. Other operations on the GUI, like rendering or animations, will continue to work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! If you would post this as an answer, I'll gladly accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

async/ await will not block any GUI. Your other operations will go on as it is. This is what we called asynchronous programming in dart.